# Adding values into added columns

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add values into a couple columns that I just added

INSERT INTO countries (currency,dialect) VALUES ('Peso','Tagalog');

the values show up below the last row. How do I get it on the 1st row?

Sorry for the stupid question, I've just started learning.

[practice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0vaC.png)

Comment: you need to do an update instead of an insert

Comment: @Jayvee oh I see! Thank you so much!